# Why won't my rspec controller test for object equivalence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This returns a false test every time.  I also used the be_an_instance_of matcher.

```
 def new
   @partner_setting = PartnerSetting.new

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @partner_setting }
end


it 'assigns a valid partner settings object to @partner_setting' do
  expect( assigns(:partner_setting) ).to be_an PartnerSetting
end
```

Comment: I assume you did call the controller somewhere (`get :new`), didn't you? (BTW. you should use `be_a` matcher here)

Comment: I'm a total derp!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your test to go to a controller action. How else will it know what to test? So before your expect, you need to add.

```
get :new
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a

```
   get :new
```

in your code. You have to call a controller action first.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note:

```
it 'the action assigns a non nil and valid Object to @partner_setting' do  
  expect(assigns(:partner_setting)).should_not be_nil
  expect(assigns(:partner_setting)).to be_an Object
end
```

WORKS!!! Even if get #new ISN'T called!

The default action is to redirect to sign in page!